# Bread Crumb Pattern in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, breadcrumbs, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I am developing an asp.net mvc 2.0 application in which I want to implement bread crumb pattern but I don't know how to implement it in asp.net. By browsing different sites I come to know about MVCSiteMap Provider but I don't know how to use it and how I can implement bread crumb in asp.net mvc 2.0 using mvcsitemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it works the same way in MVC2 but here's a quick tutorial for MVC3

http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/09/20/mvc-sitemap-provider-tutorial-2-breadcrumbs/